# extract text between multiple two brackets

Tags: javascript

I have these variables below :

```
let x = '5(2+1(3(4-1))';
let y = [];
```

I need to extract any string between `()` and **push** to `array` to be output like:

```
console.log(y); // Array should be y[4-1,3,2+1,5]
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: Use a RDP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: Parsing arithmetic expressions with parentheses: http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/12/16/recursive-descent-parser-for-arithmetic-expressions-with-real-numbers/

Comment: Given the flattened structure doesn't represent the nesting of original expressions or any relationships between them you may as well just use `x.split(/\(|\)/g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this regex

```js
let x = '5(2+1(3(4-1))';
let y = [];

let regex = /\(?(\d+([+-]\d+)?)/gm;
let m
while ((m = regex.exec(x)) !== null) {
  y.push(m[1])
}
y = y.reverse()
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by recursivly applying a regex getting and replacing the inner most () pair until only the last 5 is left, or by building a real parser.

Depending on how the input can look regex might not work.

But there exist no simple solution and it will depend on exactly what format you might get.